# Github, my branch is behind master but it is correct. How do I overwrite master with the branch?

Tags: git, branch

These are the steps I did on my way to this question:

[How to remove duplicated commits from filter-branch command on git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403472/how-to-remove-duplicated-commits-from-filter-branch-command-on-git?noredirect=1#comment81760838_47403472)

My branch A which only has 300 commits is 900 commits behind master. However, the 900 commits that I removed on branch A are duplicates. How can I just make master have 300 commits like branch A?

Comment: you want to merge your branch to master or you want to remove the commits from master?

Comment: Remove the commits from master, but they are already removed on that other branch

Comment: then just merge the branch A(in which you removed 900 duplicate commits) to your master? Are you getting merge conflicts or it says your branch is behind the master?

Comment: In the case of behind master, you might need to use force push if your the only person working on the repo or else other option is to use merge flag for fast forward.

Comment: Branch A is behind master. I tried force pushing Branch A into master and nothing happened.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31036317/240564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See original question: [How to remove duplicated commits from filter-branch command on git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403472/how-to-remove-duplicated-commits-from-filter-branch-command-on-git/47446213#47446213)

This didn't seem to be working:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard correct_branch
git push -f origin master
```

So I did:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard old_commit_id_from_master
git push -f origin master
```